# How to change db in django depending on request.get_host()?

Tags: python, django, django-middleware, django-orm

I am creating multisites platform. Anybody can make simple site, with my platform. I plan to use django multidb support. One db for one site. And i need to change db settings depending on request.get_host(). 
I think that i's not good idea. Prompt other decisions? How it is realised on various designers of sites?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to reconsider using a separate db for reach site. In reviewing the multi-db source, it looks like you'll run into a few scalability issues, depending on how many sites you want to support:

Currently all the databases are set up in *settings.py*. This could cause a few issues:

- Each new site would require reloading Django.
- settings.py could get large.

A better approach might to use a single DB and associate the site/account with each record as needed.

Comment: If it's low, and you're doing it manually, you're probably OK; otherwise, I would use a different strategy.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up one site for each "site", with it's own settings file, listening to it's own socket, using the same codebase. I'm doing that and I can easily support more than 30 concurrent sites on a middle-size server. Maintainability of configurations and startup scripts is the only issue.